# Actionscript 3.0: resizing images

Tags: actionscript-3, image-manipulation, loader, blackberry-playbook

I'm very very new on ActionScript 3.0 for mobile development.

I'm using loader class to load images. I'm loading ten images with different sizes. I'm trying to load them with a common size (300x300) doing this:

```
imageWordLoader = new Loader();
imageWordLoader.load(myImageLocation);
imageWordLoader.x = 20;
imageWordLoader.y = 60;
imageWordLoader.height = 300;
imageWordLoader.width = 300;
addChild(imageWordLoader);
```

But, I can't see anything.

How can I do that?

Comment: Has your question been successfully answered? Please accept an answer of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this to resolve my problem:

```
imageWordLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadedEvent);
```

Now, I can use `Event.COMPLETE`, but if I use Timo answer, I can't use that event.

And `onLoadedEvent` function is:

```
private function onLoadedEvent(event:Event):void
{
    var targetLoader:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);

    targetLoader.content.height = 300;
    targetLoader.content.width = 300;
}
```

Thanks for all of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until image is loaded and loader has non-zero width and height. Setting width or height on empty DisplayObject messes its transformation matrix up.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width and height after loading is complete.

Before calling load(), add an event listener:

```
imageWordLoader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete );
```

And create the event handler function:

```
function onLoadComplete( event:Event )
{
    imageWordLoader.removeEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete );
    imageWordLoader.width = 300;
    imageWordLoader.height = 300;
}
```

Comment: Now, it's working, but I'm getting another error: Warning: 3D DisplayObject will not render.  Its dimensions (6711131, 6711131) are too large to be drawn. My image is bigger than 300px.